# Как можно передать webhook запрос чтобы получить данные в проекте с ботом telegram

Tags: python, json, aiogram, post, webhook

Есть определенный проект в нем есть бот,как можно передать webhook запрос с данными в проект питон.И если возможность как-то сделать так чтобы при отсутствии интернета этот webhook как то "остановился" до момента включения обратно(я думал сделать 2 бота и с помощью telegram api отправлять своему боту сообщение, но бот не читает сообщения бота)webhook передает смс с телефона для автоматического входа в систему с помощью программы incoming sms.ip на компьютере скорее всего серый(модем)